# JSON processing using Hazelcast Jet

Tags: json, hazelcast-jet

I'm using PostgreSQL as database.

```
-------------------------
id   |  name   | value  |
-------------------------
 1   |  john   |  {"id":"0001"}
-------------------------
```

Above is simple JSON but in the application level JSON is very big. So once we upload json data into jet how to process json data by creating a pipelines in Hazelcast Jet. Any simple suggestions would be helpful to get start on this.

Comment: The question is quite broad. You can use `Sources.jdbc()` or `PostgresCdcSources` to create a batch or streaming job, the JSON document will be one of the fields, from there you can then process it using Java JSON libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two modes how to get data from PostgreSQL to Jet:

1/ Batch mode, where Jet obtains the data based on the SQL query you provide. See the [code sample](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jet/blob/master/examples/jdbc/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/jet/examples/jdbc/JdbcSource.java#L49). This mode is available via [JDBC source](https://jet-start.sh/docs/api/sources-sinks#jdbc) and produces a ResultSet that you map to your domain object.

2/ Streaming mode, where Jet subscribes to the changes to the DB tables and gets notified for any INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE. The event contains the new row value. See the [tutorial](https://jet-start.sh/docs/tutorials/cdc-postgres). This mode is available via [PostgresCdcSource](https://jet-start.sh/docs/api/sources-sinks#change-data-capture-cdc) and produces [ChangeRecords](https://jet-start.sh/javadoc/4.4/com/hazelcast/jet/cdc/ChangeRecord.html).

Both modes give you the raw JSON as a string. You can use the [JSON](https://jet-start.sh/docs/api/more-transforms#json) operator to conveniently map the JSON data to your domain objects so that you can process them by further operators downstreams.